# Outlook code for both plain text and html format

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

Some people advice that it is good idea to sent an e-mail in both format html and plain text together in the same e-mail body as following link explains.
https://litmus.com/blog/reach-more-people-and-improve-your-spam-score-why-multi-part-email-is-important

You can see four code options below.

```
.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain
.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText
.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatUnspecified
```

You are able to select one option as following picture shows.
http://www.rocketseed.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Outlook-2010-HTML.jpg

How to sent mixed formatted e-mails even your code must include one option?

I need vb.net code for this.

Answer (score 0):

That link does not apply to Outlook: when a message is saved (or sent) all 3 flavors of the message body (plain, HTML, RTF) are synchronized. You cannot send a message from Outlook with either flavor out of sync. You can send plain text messages, html/plain, or RTF (winmail.dat), but you cannot send with plain text body out of sync of the HTML body.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052094/how-to-send-outlook-mail-both-plain-text-and-html-format?rq=1

Comment: I am sending automatic e-mails from outlook using vb.net code. I am sending 500 e-mails daily. People says that in order to avoid being spammed I should send e-mails both html and text format. Any idea?

Comment: I check my sending mails from here: http://www.mail-tester.com/  Results tell me that my mails is only in html format. Results tell me that I should add also text format.

Comment: No, Outlook never sends in HTML only. It is either plain text only, plain text and HTML, or RTF.

Comment: 1-Open your outlook. 2-Write any mail 3-Send your mail to this mail address: web-cdiFiy@mail-tester.com 4-Check your mail results here http://www.mail-tester.com/ When you check your mail results they say your mail is only html!

Comment: Send an email to your Gmail account, open it there, click the down arrow next to the Reply icon, select "Show Original".